# Looping and offsetting for conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I want my code to add conditional formatting to a range of cells.

It would highlight the entire row (I'm defining entire row from i5 to BH5 everything before it is just hidden things) red if the number in a certain cell is higher then a defined amount. It starts by checking $M5 (and checks all rows below if it is above the defined amount so M6, M7, M8,so on...), then I want it to move four columns to the right and to check $Q5.

If any of these cells are over the defined amount (we'll call it 10) then it will highlight the whole row red.

I figured I would use looping and offset as I don't want to have to type in $M5>10 $Q5>10 etc.

```vb
Sub QChelp()
    Dim colhl As Long
    Dim HLA As String
    HLA = "$M5"

    For colhl = 13 To 29 Step 4
        With Range("I5:BH300")
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
              "=OR(" & HLA & ">10)"
            With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                .SetFirstPriority
                With .Interior
                    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                    .ColorIndex = 3
                    .TintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End With
        End With
    Next colhl

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you'd instead just want to use `=OR(" & cells(5,colhl).Value & ">10)"`?  Since `HLA` is "locked in", you're essentially always using `=OR($M5>10)`.

Comment: @BruceWayne Hey Bruce thanks for the response! 

I'm getting a Run-Time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument

its on this area: 
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
          "=(" & Cells(5, colhl).Value & ">10)"

I'm guessing I'm missing something. Thanks again!

Comment: Ah, remove the `=` in the Formula.  `Formula1:="OR(" & Cells(5,colhl).Value & ">10)"`.  (As an aside why are you using `OR()` if there's only one condition? Or is that just a sample formula for your asking here on SO?)

Comment: @BruceWayne ah yes, well that was a relic from when I was thinking I might have to do each beginning part (EX: $M5, $Q5, $U5). As I thought I might have to do them all and do >10. If that makes sense.

Comment: @BruceWayne Just a quick question as I'm still new at coding, so hopefully you can have some patience.

It is doing as you said but all of my conditional formats formulas come out like so "="OR(>10)" So it is not bringing in $M5 or $Q5 ect ect. Thoughts?

Comment: Hm, try `Formula1="OR(" & cells(5,colhl).address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ">10")`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Thank you! That worked. Much appreciated and kudos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you are using a static reference...note that `HLA` never changes once you set it.

Instead, you can use the `CELLS()` reference:

```
... Formula1:="OR(" & cells(5, colhl).Address(RowAbsolute:=False) & ">10)"
```

(Also note that you don't need the starting `=` in a CF Formula in VBA)

<sub>Edit: Added `.Address(...)` per comments above.</sub>